# STRAPI - Multiple APIs on Single page Load

Tags: reactjs, strapi, headless-cms

I am designing a  landing webpage that houses many "content_types" ie templates.
The webpage has:
 - TESTIMONIALS
 - REVIEWS
 - RATINGS 
 -AboutUs and many other sections.

From STRAPI, we have different APIs for testimonials, reviews, ratings etc.
Should my landing page call multiple APIs ie getTestimonials, getReviews, getRatings for that page?

Or should I create a COMMON API with all the content and call that like getContentForLandingPage and load all in one go?

What is a suggested practice?

Comment: Is there only one page?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new ContentType LandingPage with all relations.